# Meaning of "Any two deterministic quantities are independent"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence

I'm having trouble understanding this statement: "any two deterministic quantities are independent"

The example the text provides is as follows: 
$$Prob(\varnothing\cap\Omega) = Prob(\varnothing) = 0 = Prob(\varnothing)P(\Omega) $$
Which proves $\varnothing$ and $\Omega$ are independent.

However, we cannot say that any event A and its complement, $A^C$, is necessarily independent(at least I don't think). My question is why are two deterministic quantities are independent? (Maybe I'm just not understanding what deterministic in this context means?)

Any guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I would guess that "deterministic" means the probability is either $0$ or $1$.  (It's bound to happen or it will never happen.)  In which case, two deterministic events are clearly independent.

Comment: @WilsonGuo Related to the saulspatz comment, can you prove the following? Let $A$ be an event with $P[A]=1$.  Let $B$ be any other event.  Use the definition of _independent_ to prove that $A$ and $B$ are independent. [Hint: $B= (B\cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)$. Or perhaps just prove $A^c$ and $B$ are independent.]

Comment: @Michael
Is event B an event inside of A. So if B happens, then surely A happened as well? In which case, P(A|B) = 1 = P(A) since event B already happened.

Comment: @Michael Just dawned on me, isn't the probability of B happening just zero?

Comment: $B$ is any other event, it can have arbitrary intersection with $A$. For example if $B=A$ then $P[B]=P[A]=1$.